# Imaging/Cloning bootable media issues

Tags: clone

Having tried a multitude of imaging software such as BootIt Bare Metal, Active Disk Image, O&O DiskImage, etc none of them appear to be able to boot using their bootable media. I am unsure if this is because if I am doing some incorrectly or the device from which I am creating the bootable medium.

I have installed Windows AIK and ADK on a device that is running Windows 7 32-bit. The device does not feature UEFI nor Secure Boot. I am using this very device to create a bootable medium (WinPE) that will allow me to boot a device that is running Windows 8 64-bit and features UEFI & Secure Boot.

The intention of the bootable medium is to create an image or clone of the device that sports a pre-installed version of Windows 8 along with its native recovery partition.

Having trawled the interwebs, it appears that the bootable medium needs to be created on a device that has a 64-bit version of Windows installed so that I can boot into Windows 8. I have not had the same issue attempting to boot onto a 32-bit version of Windows 7. I don't yet have access to a 64-bit version of Windows 7 to see if there is a difference.

1. Is this a reason why none of the imaging software appear to work when using their bootable media? If so, I am unsure why this isn’t documented anywhere.
2. Is there a reason why I can’t use a 32-bit device to create bootable media for a 64-bit device that features UEFI and Secure Boot

Comment: Are you burning this onto a CD? If so, what are you using for the CD Burning software?

Comment: @Davidw - Yes. I have tried using both CDs and DVDs and am using ImgBurn. Does it matter what burning software I am using because I am able to use the same media for a Windows 7 device?

Comment: Is the CD drive the first drive in the boot order?

Comment: @Davidw - Yes it is.

Comment: Not sure if the burning software is the problem. You might try Active @ISO burner, which I've had lots of success with. I burned a Clonezilla disk with it and was able to clone the hard drive of my tower to a new bigger disk.

Comment: @Davidw - Don't mind trying although it seems weird that it works on a Windows 7 32-bit device and not a Windows 8 64-bit UEFI Secure Boot device

Comment: @Davidw - Are you using CloneZilla with a Windows 8 UEFI Secure Boot enabled device?

Comment: No, Windows 7 64bit. Does your motherboard have a TPM?

Comment: This might indicate why the difference: Explore Secure Boot, also referred to as Trusted Boot, a new security feature in Windows 8 that leverages the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) to block the loading and operation of any program or driver that has not been signed by an OS-provided key, and thus protects the integrity of the kernel, system files, boot-critical drivers, and even antimalware software.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj737995.aspx

Comment: @Davidw - It appears that if the bootable media is created in a similar architecture device e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit, it works. I tested it by creating the media on a 64-bit version of Windows 7 that that does not utilize UEFI & Secure Boot. It is able to boot a Windows 8 device that does use UEFI & Secure Boot.

Comment: @Davidw. It seems that when using AIK and ADK to create WindowsPE bootable disks, the platform e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit makes a difference. Although it appears you can use the same media on 32-bit devices. I'll need to run a few more tests.